# Quadratic vs. linear basis for least squares

Tags: regression, mathematical-modeling, least-squares

For least squares approximation, when is it appropriate to choose a linear basis vs. a quadratic basis?

Linear basis:

$\phi = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & y & z
\end{bmatrix}$

Quadratic basis:
$\phi = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & x & y & z & xy & xz & yz & x^2 & y^2 & z^2
\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first ("linear") basis corresponds to a first order Taylor expansion of some $f(x,y,z)$,
   $$
   f(x, y, z) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2y + \beta_3z + \epsilon
   $$ while the second one - is second order Taylor expansion of $f(x, y, z)$.

$$
f(x, y, z) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2y + \beta_3z +
\beta_4 xy 
+
\beta_5 xz
+
\beta_6 yz
+
\beta_7 x^2
+\beta_8 y^2
+\beta_9 z^2
+ \xi
$$

2. You don't have to use all the "extra" terms in the "quadratic" basis. You can take any subset of them.
3. Reasons to prefer one over another are mainly theoretical or logical. E.g., assume that $x$ is income and $y$ is country, while $f(x, y, z)$ it is happiness as a function of income, country and something else. By including $x ^ 2$ you assume that there is some maximum level of income $x_0$ that from this point and on - the happiness decreases with income, i.e., 
   $$
   \frac{\partial }{\partial x } \mathbb{E}[f|x,y,z] = \beta_1 + 2 \beta_7 x_0 = 0,
   $$
   i.e., the estimated $x_0$ is 
   $$
   \hat{x_0} = - \frac{\hat{\beta}_1}{2\hat{\beta}_7}.
   $$
   A possible reason to include terms of the form $xy$ ("interactions") is when you suspect that income $x$ contributes differently in different countries. I.e., let us say $y$ is $1$ if the subject from Canada and $0$ if he is from the UK. As such, the "contribution" of income in Canada to the level of happiness is $\beta_1 + \beta_4$, while in the UK is only $\beta_1$.
4. You can start from the quadratic basis and perform variable selection to test whether the linear basis is suffice to your needs.

Comment: So, would it be accurate to say that, in terms of accuracy, the quadratic basis would ALWAYS yield better results than the linear basis since the quadratic basis is the linear basis plus some extra terms that capture other behaviors/relationships, if present?

Comment: If your model is not driven by some theoretical considerations, then it would be plausible to start with the quadratic basis and then drop the extra terms if they turn out to be unnecessary.

Comment: Do you know the theoretical order of accuracy of the linear basis and quadratic basis when it comes to using least squares to evaluate gradients?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. But maybe you can try to ask another question here or on "Cross-Validated" as least squares and estimation ("evaluation") are basic statistical notions.

Comment: Another question: Is it correct to say that the quadratic basis will ALWAYS be more (or on par) accurate than the linear basis?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Comment: How are those $\beta$ coefficients determined? When I've seen quadratic basis used in least squares, i usually see the following $\beta_i = 1$ for $i=0:6$ and $\beta_i = 1/2$ for $i = 7:9$

Comment: Least squares indeed. what you wrote is Taylor's coeff. of the second order polynomial expansion of some $f$

Comment: Ah I see. My least squares formulation is $u(x) = [(Z^T*Z)^{-1}Z^Tq]^T\nabla \phi(x)$, where $Z$ is the matrix such that each row is the basis functions evaluated at the data point's x coordinates. But I simply use the coefficients in my previous comment for computing $Z$ and $\phi(X)$. Is that technically no longer "least squares," because, as you state, I am using the Taylor's coefficients?